# Windows Mobile 7 - C# Changing image source at run time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, runtime, bitmapimage

I'm trying to change the source of an image at run time in order to change the image after it is tapped. Thus far, the code I have below seems to result in the image turning blank.

```
BitmapImage imgSource = 
            new BitmapImage(new Uri("/PivotApp1;component/Images/halfstar.png"));
image1.Source = imgSource;
```

Is there something special that needs to be done to change a resource image at run time? I've tried searching through google, however, thus far each similar situation has resulted in a blank image. I thought maybe the source uri was wrong, but I've ruled that out as not being the cause since this is the uri when the default image is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell that the URI is Relative

```
BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(
          new Uri("/PivotApp1;component/Images/halfstar.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

and

Try setting source to null before assigning you ImageSource

```
image1.Source = null;
image1.Source = imgSource;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I guess it needed to have the UriKind.Relative thrown in.